# Snap Package installation in Chroot environment

Tags: apt, snap, synaptic, aptitude, chroot

I have a Chroot ubuntu environment installed in my Ubuntu 18.04 host computer.

When I try to install a snap package in the chroot environment, the package gets installed in my host computer and not in the chroot environment.  I am not getting this issue with apt packages

I know that the issue is caused as chroot  environments can't run their own system services like snapd...

Is there work around available?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the [bug report from 2016](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1609903) (unresolved as of September 2020):

> **Bug Description**
>
> Cloud images are built using livecd-rootfs and then modified for
> specific clouds by using chroot to modify the contents of the image
> (without ever booting it).
>
> In order to use snaps to deliver functionality required by clouds on
> first boot (generally speaking, the agents that they provide), we need
> some way of installing snaps within these chroots.
>
> Currently, running `snap install ...` within a chroot fails because
> snapd is (of course) not running.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that almost all snap packages are present in flatpak manager and flatpak is working in chroot

For now there seems to be no work around for snap to work in chroot